# Concise version of MATLAB code

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

Please see this MATLAB code:

```matlab
k=0:8;
wk=2 * pi * k/17;
ak=double(wk<0.5*pi)
```

It generates `ak` with such a simple expression. To generate `ak` in Mathematica, I have done as follows:

```
 wk = 2 π*Range[0, 8]/17
 ak = Table[wk[[i]] < π/2, {i, 9}] // Boole
```

> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}

But I think my expression is verbose compared to the MATLAB code.
Is there a concise way of generating `ak` that is even simpler than that offered by MATLAB?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you used three commands in MATLAB.

```matlab
>> k=0:8
k =
     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8

>> wk=2 * pi * k/17
wk =
 0    0.3696    0.7392    1.1088    1.4784    1.8480    2.2176    2.5872    2.9568

>> ak=double(wk<0.5*pi)
ak =
     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
>>
```

Here they are in Mathematica syntax:

```
 k = Range[0, 8]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
wk = 2*Pi*k/17
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Boole[Thread[wk < 1/2*Pi]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I do not see much difference, except in Mathematica it is done using exact computation and in MATLAB it uses machine numbers (less accurate).

Answer (score 8):

```
Boole[(2 π #)/17 < π/2] & /@ Range[0, 8]
```

---

*Result:*

> {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}

Comment: No variables :)

Comment: But you are supposed to use variables like in Matlab :)

Comment: @Nasser don’t worry, you can do the same in MATLAB without variables too: `double((2*pi*(0:8)/17)<(0.5*pi))`

Answer (score 6):

Maybe

```
wk=2 π Range[0,8]/17;ak=UnitStep[π/2-wk]
```

> Out[]= {1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0}

Also if you'd like inequality version close to yours - this would do it:

```
wk < π/2 // Thread // Boole
```